# SwiftUI Navigation does not remove previous view

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

in one of my SwiftUI views I have this Navigation link

```
 NavigationLink(destination: SomeView(), isActive: .constant(true)) {
 }.hidden()
```

and I also disabled the navigation bar on all my views.

The NavigationLink is rendered if a certain condition is true. The navigation itself works just fine, but if I swipe from the left border of the screen to the right, the old view is still there. How can I completely destroy the previous view after navigation to the next?

I also cannot use a button to navigate so there is no possibility to call additional code before navigation.

Comment: In Simple words, do you want to set your new View as rootView?

Comment: You don't need NavigationLink/NavigationView for that just show SomeView conditionally with slide transition.

Comment: if this is possible, yes ^^ but how can I switch the root view from inside the child view?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63084112/12299030?

Comment: partly, how can my child view tell the root view to switch to the other one? I'm really new to iOS development

Comment: You can simply disable popSwipeGesture.

Comment: how do I do this?